# Positioning forms according to system resolution using c# windows?

Tags: c#

I am working on a c# windows application where, user will have a tab control which is placed on bottom of the screen [exactly where windows task bar is there.] Everything is perfect except the position of form which has tab control.

when i run this application with a resolution of 1680 X 1050, the position is perfect with the below code. But this application will also be running in 800 X 600.

How can i do this ? I want the position to be generic on resolution. Thanks.

The code that works for 1680 X 1050 resolution.

```
 private void TaskBar_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                this.DesktopLocation = new Point(0, 1020); 
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you find the screen that the form is located on.

```
Screen screen = Screen.FromControl(this); // Gets the screen where the form starts
```

or

```
Screen screen = Screen.PrimaryScreen; // Gets the primary screen (if user has many screens)
```

Then you find the size and location of that screen in

```
screen.WorkingArea
```

That should help you position your form.

**Edit:** Note that `screen.WorkingArea` has already removed the pixels occupied by the taskbar.